# Select a div within a while of divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, selector, each

How to select a div among a set of divs have the same class? these divs retrieved from a database and shown using a mysql_fetch_array while.
Coz I wanna use/edit information included within each one of these divs.

Any way of act is welcome: jquery, javascript, ..

Regards!

Comment: What does the html look like, what have you already tried? How do you plan to interact with, 'use/edit,' the information? Does it have to be saved to the server for future clients, or is it just for the current client?

Comment: Yes, I should validate the modification I've done for each div, what do u suggest David?

Answer (score 2):

You can use jQuery's [`:eq`](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) selector and/or [`.eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) function (and their derivatives `:first`/`.first()`, `:last`/`.last()`, ...) to select a specific `div` amongst a set of `div`s by index, if that's what you're asking.

E.g.:

```
var thirdFooDiv = $("div.foo:eq(2)"); // Third one, first is 0
```